# putFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am new to React Native and am trying to create an app for a charity.

I am having issues when trying to store images taken with the camera in Firebase storage.

The code fragment is below, and looking at the console logs everything looks as I would expect, also below.

The error I get is "imageRef.Putfile is not a function'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CONSOLE LOG OUTPUT**

```
ref, image, imageName breadalert-86646.appspot.com file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Frn-complete-guide-10d15822-a070-46a4-a2a0-98550f263c74/ImagePicker/8211188f-6bf4-4aaf-a3ba-e187b1e3707f.jpg CKhLXQlDUtUvKotCYQmJLmOeI1s247
getting storage ref of breadalert-86646.appspot.com
firebaseStorageRef is gs://breadalert-86646.appspot.com/
Image is gs://breadalert-86646.appspot.com/CKhLXQlDUtUvKotCYQmJLmOeI1s247
Image Path is file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Frn-complete-guide-10d15822-a070-46a4-a2a0-98550f263c74/ImagePicker/8211188f-6bf4-4aaf-a3ba-e187b1e3707f.jpg
```

**CODE FRAGMENTS**

```
 saveImage = (ref, image, imageName, onSuccess, onError) => {


  console.log ('ref, image, imageName ' + ref + ' ' + image + ' ' + imageName);
  console.log ('getting storage ref of ' + ref);

  firebaseStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  console.log ('firebaseStorageRef is ' + firebaseStorageRef);

  imageRef = firebaseStorageRef.child(imageName);
  console.log ('Image is ' + imageRef);
  console.log ('Image Path is ' + image);



  imageRef.putFile (image.path, {contentType: 'image/jpeg'}).then(function(){
      return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
  }).then(function(url){
    console.log ("Image url", {url:url});
      onSuccess(url);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log ("Error while saving the image.. ", error);
      onError(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing ``putFile`` to just ``put``?

Answer (score 1):

Your `imageRef` is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) type object.  Take a look look at the linked API documentation - it has no method called `putFile()`.  That's what the error message is telling you.

If you want to upload a file, you should use the method named [put()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) instead as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files).